# Glary Utilities showing a lot more trash size for IE than there really is?

Tags: internet-explorer, temporary-internet-files

Glary Utilities is showing that Internet Explorer temporary internet files size is more than 6GB.

As a sane person I don't use IE. I looked up the temp folder and there are 43 files with total size of less than 85MB.

Am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you the only user? Other programs that use IE components might also add to those files I believe and there might be more than just the directory in your User profile. Ultimately it depends on how that software detects that size.

Comment: You seem to have cache entries from http://www.glarysoft.com, despite not using IE. I would guess that one of your other browsers is using some shared DLLs from IE, and this is causing other cached entries to be logged against IE.

Comment: I see BliskInstaller in there but I don't use Blisk browser either, it's a mobile developer browser and I use it just to see how a webpage looks on mobile devices, and those webpages are local, I don't use it to access the Internet, and it seems like it uses Chrome engine. I'm puzzled because I only use FF.